# OpenCV: How to create a mask in the shape of a polygon?

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

I have a list of points which are the vertices of a polygon, like this:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2d> polygonPoints;
```

I need to create a mask for the `goodFeaturesToTrack` function in openCV. For a rectangle, the easiest way to fill the desired area with `1`'s is like this:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U);
mask(boundingbox) = 1;
```

How do I do this with a polygon that has 10+ edges? Is there an equivalent solution for n-sided polygons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Managed to find an answer that works!

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img->rows, img->cols, CV_8U);
cv::Point pts[5] = {
    cv::Point(1, 6),
    cv::Point(2, 7),
    cv::Point(3, 8),
    cv::Point(4, 9),
    cv::Point(5, 10)
};
cv::fillConvexPoly( mask, pts, 5, cv::Scalar(1) );
```

Comment: Nice! And combined with triangulation, you can take care of any closed contour set of points this way.

Comment: After looking up `cv::fillConvexPoly` I found `cv::fillPoly`. So it seems that OpenCV can also handle more complex sets of points.